# How can I know if a node exists or not

Tags: xml, asp-classic

here is the response xml I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns="urn:ws.paymentech.net/PaymentechGateway">
- <SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0">
- <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode> 
  <faultstring>521 Error. The Orbital Gateway has received a badly formatted message. Field [Card Number] exceeded max length of [19]</faultstring> 
  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

i get it like this:

```
Response.write oXmlHTTP.responseXML.xml
```

I have tried

```
if myXML.selectSingleNode("faultcode") Is Nothing then

if not isObject(myXML.selectSingleNode("faultcode")) then
```

both true on 2 cases where the xml has this node and even if it doesn't have it

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps

```
Set faultCodeNode = myXML.selectSingleNode("faultcode")

If faultCodeNode Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: i will try it but what is the difference with 2 steps?